# Importing namespaces in Laravel Tinker REPL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel's Tinker REPL is useful for conveniently experimenting with models, however it does not seem possible to import a namespace, requiring the model namespace to be laboriously typed. For instance, this works:

```
$ php artisan tinker
[1] $list = new mysweetapp\Todolist;
[2] > echo get_class($list);
mysweetapp\Todolist
```

This does not:

```
$ php artisan tinker
[1] use mysweetapp\Todolist;
// false
[2] $list = new Todolist;
[3] echo get_class($list);
Boris\EvalWorker
```

Is there some way to import namespaces into Tinker or is it just not yet supported? Mind you I definitely want to use namespaces, I just don't want to repeatedly type in the namespace. :-)

Comment: Update: As of 5.0 it works just like you'd expect :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this https://softonsofa.com/tinker-like-a-boss-in-psysh/

---

You can't do this with `use namespace` in the repl itself, but here's what you may do:

```
// config/local/app.php
'aliases' => append_config([
    'Todolist'   => 'Mysweetapp\Todolist',
    ... // more
]),
```

Then in your local env you will be able to access your models without typing namespace, and if you're not in local env, then run tinker forcing it:

```
php artisan tinker --env=local
```